# Java - File Download makes Program Stop

Tags: java, multithreading, download, window, fileoutputstream

When I download a file in Java with the following code, i can't use the Program anymore, it's not responding. But when the Download finishs i can use it again.

```java
URL website = new URL("MY_URL");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("grafik");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

How do I fix that? E.g. that a loading screen is showed or that a dialog pops up?
Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: Stick long-lasting I/O on another thread instead of your user interaction thread

Comment: If you need to wait for the download anyway, the easiest thing to do would be open a dialog before you start the download and display a loading gif, then close the dialog after the download finishes.

Comment: use a seperate thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to learn about the wonderful world of [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)!

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL website = new URL("MY_URL");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("grafik");
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}).start();
```

Doing this will launch a separate thread -- essentially another line of execution hat acts independently of the one it's spawned from.  This will allow your user interface to continue to function while this activity happens separately.

Concurrency can be very tricky, though, once you start wanting the different threads to interact.  Definitely take a look at the Oracle tutorial linked in this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a java desktop application and use Swing, [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is a nice way to do time consuming background tasks. It has built in support for updating progress info.